# How to have mutually-independent text side by side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column

How could I create two columns that are arranged side by side. By side by side I mean that, the one on the left is flushed to the right and the one on the right is flushed to the left. Also, they need to be mutually independent, in other words have to be able to support texts in different amounts without the text flushed to the right (e.g.) is concatenated to the other column that has text to the left.

I've made this try but it isn't sufficient, as if the text on the first column which  is flushed right is much larger then it gets concatenated with the second column, which should only have the text flushed to the left. This is shown in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
% -> %
\begin{flushright}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{flushright}
% -> %


% <- %
\begin{flushleft}
\lipsum[2]
\end{flushleft}
% <- %

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Could you please give me a hand, as it is beyond my current knowledge

It is for organizing lyrics and the translation side by side

Comment: The text will be contained in a single page or do you require that this two-column layout keeps across page boundaries?

Comment: It isn't fully required that the text keeps the layout across page boundaries as the majority of the text will be only one page. As long as there is a Workaround-oriented programming way to use it when the text is close to 3 pages long it's more than fine.

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave and couldn't answer you. I was going to suggest inserting a `\columnbreak` between the columns, but this doesn't work if the text flows to the next page. Apparently Mr. Marmot's answer is the way to go :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use paracol for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
% -> %
\begin{flushright}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{flushright}
% -> %

\switchcolumn

% <- %
\begin{flushleft}
\lipsum[2]
\end{flushleft}
% <- %

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]